# How many times increment will be executed?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following code

```
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j)
        {
           if(a[i] + a[j] == 0)
           { ++cnt;}
        }
    }
```

Where N is a number of elements in the array.

I started to learn algorithms and I trying to find how many times increment will be executed?

For `i` it will be `N` times.

For `j` it will be `N-1` times when `i = 0`, `N-2` when `i = 1` etc.
So `N-1 + N-2 + ... + 0 = ((0 + N-1)/2)*N = N*(N-1)/2`

So how many times `cnt++` will be executed?

To answer for this question we need to find how many times `==` will be executed? Of course it will be in range. From `0` to some value. And our final answer will be in the range from `0 + number of(++i) + number of(++j)` to `some value +  number of(++i) + number of(++j)`.

Let's find this `some value`

It will be `1...N-1` when `i=0`, `2...N-2` when `i=1` etc
so `N-1 + N-2 + ... + 0 = N*(N-1)/2`

So the answer will be from `N*(N-1)/2` to `N + N(N-1)/2 + N(N-1)/2`, so from 
`N*(N-1)/2 to N^2`

But R.Sedgwick said at the 33 slide that  http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring15/cos226/lectures/14AnalysisOfAlgorithms.pdf

the answer will be from `N*(N+1)/2 to N^2`

Why? Am I wrong? Where?

Comment: Good questions. I think that you are right

Comment: `how many times cnt++ will be executed` That's going to depend on the array itself, and not on its size, unless I am missing something, it will execute 0 times for `[1,2,....,n]`.

Comment: What items does `a` array contain? Imagine that `a` has positive items only, in that case `a[i] + a[j] == 0` will never be true and the answer is  *zero*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko unless if you consider that 0 is a positive number, but that's not the point here

Comment: How could the number of  `++cnt` exceed the number of `==` ?

Comment: @Thomas strictly speaking, 0 is not positive, it is 'non-negative'. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nonnegative.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Positive.html.

Comment: You forgot an `N +` term.

Comment: Well, go on and execute it, print out cnt at the end and you'll see. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner loop (`==` test) is indeed executed `N(N-1)/2` times.

For this reason, the increment `(++cnt`) is potentially executed between `0` and `N(N-1)/2` times.

These two bounds can be reached: `0` when all `a[k] > 0`, and `N(N-1)/2` when all `a[k] == 0`.

---

For the total count of increments, add `N` for the outer `for` loop and `N(N-1)/2` for the inner `for` loop, and get between `N(N+1)/2` and `N²` inclusive.

Comment: "between 0 and N(N-1)/2 times." Yes, but also we need to add to this range number of time that will be executed `++i` and `++j`

Comment: Your problem statement is ambiguous as it is unclear if you want to count ++cnt or all of ++cnt, ++i, ++j.

Comment: Yes, I want to count all